# Moving beyond high end microcontrollers to high performance computation embedded systems

Tags: cpu, gpu

I have been working a with relatively fast and high end microcontrollers now, and I want to move beyond them. For example, I've been using the STM32F4 chip, which has something of a 180MHz and a decent amount of memory. Now I want to move beyond these "high end" microcontrollers. I want to develop platforms which are in the GHz-range, which can manage a lot of calculations, and also work together with an embedded GPU. The application I want to use it for is in the automotive industry, where there's a lot of data processing and algorithm calculations.

As I understand it, the next step is somewhat more complicated. You need a separate memory, RAM, storage, and a lot of other peripheral components to support the chip. I'm not looking for an embedded computer platform like the beagleboard or RBP, where you run an OS. I would like to run an RTOS where you can crunch decent amount of numbers (lidar data, image processing), and manage real-time requirements.

For example, if some tech company which develops autonomous vehicles wanted a prototyping platform (and I say prototyping cause it would probably be an ASIC in production) where they can do a lot of dataprocessing and algorithms, what type of embedded system would they use?

So my questions is: What lies beyond the high en microcontrollers? Could someone give me an overview of how embedded systems are built up in this domain?

Comment: Usually in the industry, if you want to step up your technology, you hire someone with the experience in that technology rather than asking weird people on the interwebs...

Comment: It's a question soliciting opinions and should be closed.

Comment: The requirements you describe (High end, GHz-range, embedded GPU, ...) are a perfect fit for most Cortex-A implementations, including the processors used in the beaglebone/RBP. And you can have such chips running a RTOS instead of a mainstream linux. You can use whatever OS you want. So why do you rule them out ?

Comment: @PlasmaHH This is a private project, not for my company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most microprocessors with gpus end up in embedded computers anyway, but if you want real grunt and aren't afraid of some not-so-user-friendly programming languages, check out Altera's Cyclone V SoC or Xilinx's Zynq, multicore Arm chips coupled with not insubstantial amounts of FPGA logic, DDR3 support and dedicated gpus. For sheer computational grunt (but not on-the-fly flexibility) it's hard to beat an FPGA, you can even compile arduino code for an FPGA. (P.S. you don't *have* to run a full OS on a pi or a BB, you can always load an RTOS, you can load an RTOS on almost anything with an IO pin, it's just more complicated)